# Is it possible to grab data from in memory javascript objects from a WebApp via external means?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, browser, heap-memory

Suppose we have a token that is supposed to be super secure sitting in memory in a javascript variable.  Is it possible for a hacker to grab the token from memory?

I'm evaluating whether I should be adding additional cryptography for highly sensitive data.

This could include computational data loaded via JSON or CSV into the browser.  We want to make sure it's safe from any type of process that might be able to read the in memory javascript browser objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** (*Probably*).  Depending on what is executing the javascript, whether that is nodejs on a server,  or a browser on a client, it *is* running in a process somewhere.  Most modern operating systems protect data in a user process from processes running as a different user.  However, processes running as the same user generally have the ability to affect each other.  If your process requires isolating the sensitive memory contents of the javascript token from an attacker who may have gained access to the same operating system, you must run the process as a separate user from the attacker to have any safety.  If you are running this in a browser, then consider everything in that javascript payload to be readable (and writeable) by a malicious user, or by malware running on the operating system of an innocent user.  If you are running the javascript in an environment you control, then you can certainly isolate that process by running it as a user that cannot be accessed by other (malicious) users on the same operating system.

If the token you want to send to a javascript application running on a untrusted client environment contains information you wouldn't want to make public, then encrypt it server-side, and do not send the keys to the client side to decrypt it.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration - Any thoughts on computational data - For example we may be performing analysis for clients in the browser, but it's highly sensitive data and we would not want any other client / browser process to be able to peak at it while it's in memory.  The data could be loaded via CSV or JSON from the desktop, and we want to make sure it's protected from snooping from any operating system process or browser hacking techniques.

Comment: Updated the question adding the computational data part.

Comment: Found this resource on the topic - It has a pretty good overview of what might occur with browser data: https://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/